# Exact value of Hausdorff measure of two dimensional Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fractals, geometric-measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

Let $\mathcal{C}$ denote the classical Cantor set, then it is well-known that $\mathcal{C}$ has Hausdorff dimension $\alpha = \ln 2 /\ln 3$, and its $\alpha$-dimensional Hausdorff measure is $\mathcal{H}_\alpha(\mathcal{C}) = 1$.

For $\mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}\subset \mathbb{R}^2$, it is fairly easy to show its Hausdorff dimension is $2\alpha$, and $0< \mathcal{H}_{2\alpha}(\mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C}) <\infty$. I am interested in **knowing the exact value of** $\mathcal{H}_{2\alpha}(\mathcal{C}\times \mathcal{C})$.

The proof for 1D case $\mathcal{H}_\alpha(\mathcal{C}) = 1$ cannot carry directly into higher dimension.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1769915/exact-value-of-hausdorff-measure-of-middle-third-cantor-set) claims the measure is $1$ and refers to Falcon's book *The Geometry of Fractal Sets*. However, after really looking into the book, it does not say anything about Hausdorff measure (only Hausdorff dimension) for any non-1D set (at least at the position quoted).

Nonetheless, it might be possible that the Hausdorff measure does not admit a simple closed-form, as expected for many fractals in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with $n>1$. Any idea/reference is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**Sketch for a possible solution:** we can build $C\times C$ in the same way that we build $C$, that is, starting from $C_0:=[0,1]$, $C_1:=[0,1/3]\cup[2/3,1]$ and so on then $$C\times C=\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty C_k\times C_k\tag1$$

Set $A_k:=C_k\times C_k$, then $A_k$ is composed by $4^k$ squares of side length $3^{-k}$, this means that each square have diameter $\sqrt 2/3^k$.

For measurable sets the Hausdorff measure is defined by the limit $\mathcal H^s(A)=\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\mathcal H^s_\epsilon(A)$, where

$$\mathcal H_\epsilon^s(A):=\inf\left\{\sum_{k=0}^\infty\operatorname{diam}(O_k)^s,\, \operatorname{diam}(O_k)\le \epsilon,\, A\subset\bigcup_{k=0}^\infty O_k,\, O_k\text{ is open}\right\}\tag2$$

Now we can try to approximate the value of $\mathcal H^s(A)$ from above. Suppose we are trying to cover $A$ with open squares of diameter $\gamma\sqrt 2/ 3^k$, then for enough small $\gamma>1$ it seems easy to prove (by the inner structure of $C\times C$ that can be seen in it construction) that the most efficient way to do it is covering $A$ as if we were covering $A_k$, so we will need $4^k$ of this squares. The same happen for all $k\in\Bbb N$, hence we will find that

$$\mathcal H^s(A)\le\lim_{k\to\infty} 4^k\left(\gamma\frac{\sqrt 2}{3^k}\right)^s,\quad\forall \gamma>1\tag3$$

where the inequality comes from the fact that a box-covering is less efficient than a circle-covering using the same diameter for squares and circles (because a square cover less area than a circle with the same diameter). Hence we find that $\mathcal H^s(A)\le(\sqrt 2)^s$ when we choose $s:=\ln 4/\ln 3$.

From all of this I see that if we shows that, for each $\gamma_k\sqrt 2/3^k$ (for enough small $\gamma_k>1$), the covering of circles cannot be better than the covering of boxes, that is that $\mathcal H^s_{\gamma_k\sqrt 2/3^k}(A)=4^k(\gamma_k\sqrt 2/3^k)^s$ then we will had that $$\mathcal H^s(A)=\lim_{k\to\infty}\mathcal H^s_{\gamma_k\sqrt 2/3^k}(A)=(\sqrt 2)^s$$ for $s:=\ln 4/\ln 3$.

---

About possible references: I didn't read it but, the most complete textbook that cover this questions, seems to by *Fractal geometry* of Falconer.