# Calculating Haursdorff measure of Cantor Dust and Sierpinski Carpet

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, hausdorff-measure

I am a masters student and I have taken a course on measure theory ( it is my 1 st measure theory course).

In one of initial classes professor gave defination of Haursdorff measure similar to  as given here -- 
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure.

and then immediately he gave assignment problem to find the Haursdorff measure of Cantor Dust and

Sierpinski carpet given here --- https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_carpet.

I could not solve it and found while searching on internet that Haursdorff measure of Sierpinski carpet has only been found in 1998 by Chinese mathematicians in a 8 page proof devoted entirely to it.

My professor never discusses any any assignment problems.  In fact,  he doesn't even answer doubts of students in class. So, I can't ask him.

I am thinking that 8 page proof is long enough for assignment problems.  In fact,  none of other problems were so long.

So, can someone please tell a somewhat not so lenthy approach and which doesn't uses much advanced concepts in measure theory  to find Haursdorff measure of both sierpinski carpet and Cantor dust as  this problem was given in initial lectures of 1 st course on measure theory.

Comment: Probably the assignment was (or was intended to be) to find the Hausdorff dimension, not the Hausdorff measure.  If your professor assigns problems that are too hard and never discusses them, perhaps you should talk to his superior (department head or something) and not ask here, where we can do nothing about it.

Comment: @GEdgar I completely agree about problem with professor that he never discusses . But prof.  has clearly typed to find Haursdorff measure in both cases. He hasn't even defined Haursdorff dimension. So, isn't there a relatively shorter proof?

Comment: related, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1769915 I think there are proofs in some books, do you use any particular book in your class? The above link refers to a book by Falconer http://wwwf.imperial.ac.uk/~jswlamb/M345PA46/F85%20chap%201.pdf | http://mate.dm.uba.ar/~umolter/materias/referencias/1.pdf | There are many papers on (various) Cantor sets, but there is just one Middle-Third Cantor set, and for it I believe the problem is easier.

Comment: @ Yes I study from Walter rudin Real and complex analysis. But professor never tells from where he is teaching.